# Updating Symbol table at runtime in microcontroller

Tags: c, embedded

I'm working on a project with an ARM Microcontroller and I loaded a C module (or object file) text segment to the FLASH at runtime.

But now, after loading the module, the addresses of the functions in this module are changed.

So, is it possible to change their addresses on the symbols table? And, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally absolute addresses are resolved by the linker, object modules generated by the compiler are not linked and contain symbol information that will be resolved by the linker.

To load an object module at runtime requires a runtime that is capable of performing the link and locate step dynamically.  That it is it must be able to set addresses relative to the load location and resolve any links to code already loaded (either statically or dynamically).  To achieve that the runtime must include the symbol table for the code it has already loaded as well as be able to update that symbol table with new code because the new code may be linked to existing code and if further modules are loaded that may link to previously dynamically loaded code.

It can be done, and for example VxWorks is an RTOS that allows exactly that - though to RAM rather then Flash.  However it is not a trivial task to implement from scratch, and the need to retain a symbol table containing all public symbols means that it requires significant memory resources not typically available on a microcontroller board.  The runtime must support and understand the object file format.

To dynamically link and locate to Flash it would be necessary to write the flash omitting the addresses that are yet to be resolved and retrospectively write them once the symbol table is complete.

I think knowing how it could be done you might decide it is hardly worth the effort and devise some alternative solution.

If the code is entirely stand-alone and does not need to link with existing code, then that is perhaps a simpler issue and is essentially what a bootloader does.  In that case you would create a fully linked and located binary and load it to the build-time specified  location, then have some "executive" or bootloader that selects which of multiple executables to run.  The selection would best be done following a reset to ensure the processor state is in a known state and not dependent of any previous execution.

Another solution might be to avoid any attempt to load and run native code and instead  support an embedded language interpreter, and write the dynamically loaded code in that language. Interpreters exist for languages such as Lua, implementing your own embedded scripting language is not that hard, and some languages such as FORTH are remarkably easy to implement.  In general that could be safer and more secure since the runtime system can isolate your interpreted code from the rest of the system in ways that dynamically loading an linking arbitrary object code cannot.